# Unable to enable BitLocker due to mis-configured (?) Windows Recovery Environment

Tags: windows, windows-10, encryption, bitlocker

**tl;dr**: *I failed to enable BitLocker on my tablet's system drive for the first time and now I see an error each time I restart Windows or try to enable BitLocker again. Windows claims that this is due to not configured Windows Recovery Environment and I don't know, what to do next.*

I have a Windows 10 Pro-based tablet with TPM available and wated to enable BitLocker encryption on drive C: (system drive and the only one in fact, of that matters).

I enabled it for the first time and I went through few steps of its wizard. First, Windows checked, if my hardware allows to use BitLocker. This step passed without problems. Next, I saw a screen in which Windows claimed, that it is moving Windows Recovery Environment to some other (hidden) partition. Reasons for such move remains unknown to me.

In third screen or step I saw I question, where to I want to store encryption key and three options:

- save it to Microsoft account,
- store it on USB,
- print it.

This is a tablet with only microUSB port. I didn't have microUSB-based pendrive or microUSB OTG cable when enabling BitLocker for the first time. And I have my Windows 10 with only single local account. Thus, non of above options was available for me and `Next` button was disabled.

I've clicked `X`, seen some error message and shut down my tablet.

When I started it again next day I saw following error during Windows start-up:

[image]

Now, I can see it with every Windows 10 restart. This is really weird for me, because -- as I wrote above -- BitLocker configuration was not finished and thus neither BitLocker is enabled nor encryption key is put to TPM.

Each time I try to re-enable BitLocker for C: drive I see following error:

[image]

I don't understand, how it is possible that Windows managed to move Windows Recovery Environment from `C:` drive to a hidden partition, but isn't able to move it back?

Anyway, can anyone shed some light and explain me, what should I do now or how to proceed from this point? How to move back Windows Recovery Environment manually? How to get rid of that startup error message? And the most important -- how to enable BitLocker and encrypt my system drive on my tablet?